# compile aosp failed and show errors with webrtc

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to compile , repo branches is

```
 android-2.0_r1            | in:
                               bionic
                               bootable/bootloader/legacy
                               bootable/recovery
                               build
                               cts
                               dalvik
                               development
                               external/apache-http
                               external/bison
                               external/blktrace
                               external/bsdiff
                               external/bzip2
                               external/dhcpcd
                               external/e2fsprogs
                               external/elfutils
                               external/emma
                               external/esd
                               external/expat
                               external/fdlibm
                               external/freetype
                               external/fsck_msdos
                               external/genext2fs
                               external/giflib
                               external/gtest
                               external/ipsec-tools
                               external/iptables
                               external/jdiff
                               external/jhead
                               external/jpeg
                               external/junit
                               external/libpcap
                               external/libpng
                               external/libxml2
                               external/mtpd
                               external/netcat
                               external/netperf
                               external/neven
                               external/openssl
                               external/oprofile
                               external/ppp
                               external/proguard
                               external/protobuf
                               external/qemu
                               external/safe-iop
                               external/skia
                               external/sonivox
                               external/speex
                               external/sqlite
                               external/srec
                               external/strace
                               external/svox
                               external/tagsoup
                               external/tcpdump
                               external/tinyxml
                               external/xmlwriter
                               external/yaffs2
                               external/zlib
                               frameworks/base
                               frameworks/opt/emoji
                               hardware/broadcom/wlan
                               hardware/libhardware
                               hardware/libhardware_legacy
                               hardware/ril
                               hardware/ti/omap3
                               packages/apps/Bluetooth
                               packages/apps/Browser
                               packages/apps/Calculator
                               packages/apps/Calendar
                               packages/apps/Camera
                               packages/apps/CertInstaller
                               packages/apps/Contacts
                               packages/apps/Email
                               packages/apps/Gallery
                               packages/apps/HTMLViewer
                               packages/apps/Launcher2
                               packages/apps/Mms
                               packages/apps/Music
                               packages/apps/PackageInstaller
                               packages/apps/Phone
                               packages/apps/Settings
                               packages/apps/SoundRecorder
                               packages/apps/Stk
                               packages/apps/VoiceDialer
                               packages/inputmethods/LatinIME
                               packages/inputmethods/OpenWnn
                               packages/providers/ApplicationsProvider
                               packages/providers/CalendarProvider
                               packages/providers/ContactsProvider
                               packages/providers/DownloadProvider
                               packages/providers/MediaProvider
                               packages/providers/TelephonyProvider
                               packages/providers/UserDictionaryProvider
                               packages/wallpapers/Basic
                               system/core
                               system/extras
```

gingerbread-release       | in bootable/bootloader/legacy

and I used these command

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
make
```

but after a while the compile is stopped ,and show errors below:

```
target SharedLib: libwebviewchromium (out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwebviewchromium_intermediates/LINKED/libwebviewchromium.so)
/mnt/src/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: warning: hidden symbol 'SkBitmap::lockPixels() const' in out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/skia_skia_library_gyp_intermediates/skia_skia_library_gyp.a(SkBitmap.o) is referenced by DSO out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libjnigraphics.so
/mnt/src/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: warning: hidden symbol 'SkBitmap::unlockPixels() const' in out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/skia_skia_library_gyp_intermediates/skia_skia_library_gyp.a(SkBitmap.o) is referenced by DSO out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libjnigraphics.so
/mnt/src/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: warning: hidden symbol 'SkBitmap::notifyPixelsChanged() const' in out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/skia_skia_library_gyp_intermediates/skia_skia_library_gyp.a(SkBitmap.o) is referenced by DSO out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libjnigraphics.so
external/chromium_org/content/renderer/media/webrtc/peer_connection_dependency_factory.cc:353: error: undefined reference to 'webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(rtc::Thread*, rtc::Thread*, webrtc::AudioDeviceModule*, cricket::WebRtcVideoEncoderFactory*, cricket::WebRtcVideoDecoderFactory*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwebviewchromium_intermediates/LINKED/libwebviewchromium.so] Error 1
```

I have no idea why this occurs. I didnot  change any code.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is generated by the build/make when AOSP was trying to build a Chromium (the default Android browser) library.

You're trying to compile on branch android-2.0_r1 right? This demands Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as stated by [AOSP Docs](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html). Are you sure that you have installed all needed tools (and that none of them generated errors during their installs)? You can install these tools by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Let me give some hints:

1. When you run
   **$ lunch aosp_arm-eng** you must remember that this is a "generic" build. It is much more effective if you choose the correct build in this step, for example **$ lunch aosp_hammerhead_userdebug**. Maybe you're even trying to build in wrong architectures by calling this generic build, or to a wrong devices;
2. Remember to call **make clean** and/or **make clobber** before building, to clean possible garbage from previous builds.

I hope that some of above can help you.

Comment: I'm sure I have install the software you said. I've found the reason not because the environment but the source code I downloaded.After I re-download the whole code , I compiled ok.Thanks a lot.